# Combobox Selected Items not binding correctly when using it with ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I need to bind the selected item to a property, but somehow it's not working.

Here's my attempt:

```
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Label Content="{Binding FirstProperty}"/>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SecondProperties}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProperty}" />
...
```

Here is the model that does this:

```
    private List<MyItems> _myItems;
    public List<MyItem> MyItems{
        get => _myItems;
        set
        {
            _myItems= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

And here is my class:

```
public class MyProperty
{
    public List<string> SecondProperties{ get; set; }
    public string FirstProperty;
    public string SelectedProperty;
}
```

I want that the `SelectedProperty` matches what I selected. When I use it later, `FirstProperty` is fine, the combobox list `SecondProperties` is also fine, but `SelectedProperty` is always `null`.

Any help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed your code:

```
public class MyProperty : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string selectedProperty;
     public string SelectedProperty
    {
        get 
        { 
            return selectedProperty; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            selectedProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProperty");}
        } 

 protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
 {
     if (PropertyChanged != null)
     {
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
 }
```

Add  Mode=TwoWay  in your xaml

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SecondProperties}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProperty,  Mode=TwoWay }" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I already fixed it and this is right. I just needed the getters and setters. Also I don't know who downvoted you.

Comment: Your welcome. no worries about the downvote, it doesn't matter as long your question is answered

Comment: Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raising the `PropertyChanged` event is not required for you to be able to just bind to the property. It is required if you want to subscribe to changes to the property in the view though. And the `SelectedItem` property of a `ComboBox` binds two-way by default.

Comment: thank you for your information @mm8. first INotifyPropertyChanged and raising the PropertyChanged event is not required for you to be able to just bind to the property , but i wrote for him the full code to test . second assiging Mode in xaml improve performance.

Comment: Even if "second assiging Mode in xaml improve performance" was actually true, this would be negligible.

Comment: lol @mm8  if you are bothered from my answer i can delete it; since it reached the user that asked.

Answer (score 1):

SelectedProperty must be defined as a public *property*:

```
 public string SelectedProperty { get; set; }
```

This is a public field:

```
public string SelectedProperty;
```

Comment: This would have made every SelectedProperty the same. But it gave me the hint that I need getters and setters. Also I don't know who downvoted you.

Comment: Yes, you need the `{ get; set; }` to make it a property.

Comment: because he's done exactly the same as I have done and it works (private string that is setted by the public string). Perhaps it would have sufficed with your get and set but I did not test that. I guess it does work. Still could accept both answers as correct, though.

Comment: Raising an event has no impact on the binding. And `SelectedItem` binds two-way by default.

Comment: I will test your solution and if it works I will check your answer. It would be fine if you actually informed the other user about that in his answer, too (I am fairly new to C#)